# Divergence theorem and test function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, surfaces

Consider Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ denote the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The unbounded function $$u(x) = log log(1+\frac{1}{|x|})$$ is given. Consider the compactly supported testfunction $\phi$, which vanisches on the boundary of $\Omega$

For $e>0$ it holds using divergence theorem of gauss: $$\int_{\Omega - B_e(0) }u(x) \partial_x \phi(x) + \partial_x  u(x) \phi(x)dx = \int_{\partial B_e(0)} u \phi N_i dS + \int_{\partial \Omega} u \phi N_i dS  $$

The second integral $\int_{\partial \Omega} u \phi N_i dS =0$ since $\phi$ is $0$ on the boundary.

How can I compute $N_i dS$ It is circle with radius $e$, so I can parameterize it in the following way: For each $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ the cirlce is described by $e (\cos(\theta ), (\sin(\theta )) )$ But how can I compute  the i-th component of  normalvector $N_i$ then?

Comment: Draw a picture of a circle centered at the origin. What is the outward-pointing unit normal vector?

Comment: It is orthogonal to the tangent line at each point at the circle

Comment: How can I compute it analytically

Comment: Have you taken multivariable calculus? Go review.

Comment: I am not sure since my paramerisation only depends on $theta$. So I do not with which vector I have to take the cross product.